# How do I open certain window from raster file

Tags: python, geopandas, rasterio, python-3

I have a geodataframe with some bounds and I'd like to open that specifc box from the raster file. Lets say my raster file is name `data.tiff` so my current code is like:

```
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio.windows import from_bounds
with rio.open(data.tiff) as data:
    rst = data.read(1, window=from_bounds(bounds['left'], bounds['bot'], bounds['right'], bounds['top']))
```

But I get the following error:

```
WindowError: A transform object is required to calculate the window
```

What should my affine transform be if both the raster and the geodataframe are in the same coordinate system?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the raster dataset transform.

```
with rio.open(data.tiff) as data:
    rst = data.read(1, window=from_bounds(
        bounds['left'], bounds['bot'], bounds['right'], bounds['top'], 
        data.transform)
    )
```